# Adding CDialog inside CDockablePane and application becomes unresponsive

Tags: mfc

I want to add a `CDialog` control inside `CDockablePane`. When I use `CDialog.DoModal()` to display the dialog window, it makes the MFC application unresponsive and waiting for the `CDialog` result.

How can I make the application display the dialog and continue running without waiting for the `CDialog` result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `DoModal` to display the dialog. That displays a modal dialog, which prevents interaction with any other windows in your application until the dialog has been dismissed. Just like a message box does.

To display a non-modal dialog, you call the `Create` member function. Use the instance of your `CDockablePane` as the dialog's parent. You will also need to ensure that the dialog itself is a child window, without a border.

It might be easier to use a class derived from `CFormView` or `CPaneDialog`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, now i'm using a class derived from `CPaneDialog` as you suggest, like this: 
 `m_DlgInsidePane.Create(_T("Guide"), this, FALSE, 
    IDD_DLG_TEST_IN_PANE, 
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | CBRS_LEFT | CBRS_FLOAT_MULTI, 
    0)`, but the dialog doesn't appear.
@Cody Gray

Comment: After creation add: m_DlgInsidePane.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);